# Reading rows from a string one by one

Tags: string-manipulation

I imported my data(table format) and converted it into string using **ReadString["file"]**. Here is what I got:

> [image]

Now I want to read each row of my string one by one so that I can use them in solving equations further. Substituting values from row 1, row 2, row 3 successively in my equation I would get my output accordingly. Please let me know how can I read these rows.
*Please help me with the do loop also if possible.*

Comment: You can `Import[file, "Table"]` directly.

Comment: Thanks! I got my answer.